# Code First: Create Tables but not database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have ready my model on **code first EF** and I try it on **sql express** and **it works**. But I have a problem translating it to a **sql server**:  **I don't have the permissions to recreate a database I can only add tables to an empty database**.

I already see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796612/code-first-with-existing-empty-database)  but when I'm trying to replicate it I have some troubles with the context part:

```
public class DropCreateDatabaseTables : IDatabaseInitializer<Context> {

#region IDatabaseInitializer<Context> Members



public void InitializeDatabase(Context context)
```

I already put the reference to System.Data.Entity but that don't work and the Context class not is the referenced on System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts

There is something wrong in the code? Or is a better solution with the last tools of EF?

**EDIT:**

Finally was:

DbContext:

```
public class PeopleContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Adress> Adresses{ get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Add Entity type configuration classes
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AdressConfiguration());

    }
}
```

Initializer:

```
  public class DropCreateDatabaseTables : IDatabaseInitializer<PeopleContext>
{

    public void InitializeDatabase(PeopleContextContext)
    {

      bool dbExists;

      using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))

      {

        dbExists = Context.Database.Exists();

      }

      if (dbExists)

      {       

        // remove all tables
          Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'");
          Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = \"DROP TABLE ?\"");



        // create all tables

        var dbCreationScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();

        Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript);


        Context.SaveChanges();

      }

      else

      {

          throw new ApplicationException("No database instance");

      }

    }
}
```

Call:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person= new Person
        {
            Identifier= "John Doe"
        };
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseTables());
        using (var context = new PeopleContext())
        {
            context.People.Add(person);
            context.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Lukas Kabrt!

Comment: Don't start by writing your own initializer, but use the standard ones, like `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());` See [DropCreateDatabaseAlways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Because my credentials I can't drop the database and recreate it I just can create tables over an existing empty database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Context` class in the example should be your `DbContext` class i.e. the class where you specify your `DbSet<>`s.

*Example:*

**DbContext class**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**DatabaseInitializer**

```
public class DropCreateDatabaseTables : IDatabaseInitializer<DataContext> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I try your solution, but I don't know how it does nothing: Can I edit my post with the code and you tell me if is correct?

Comment: Go ahead, I can try looking at your ... I though you have just problems with compiling your code, so I haven't written any implementation of the initializer

Comment: Don't worry it work I edited de question with the correct code. Thanks!